# how to fix loop "go to bottom" when i scroll top

Tags: javascript

After you click Go To Bottom then roll the mouse over it just automatically roll down it? way still uses the setInterval without fail no summer?
link source code
http://jsfiddle.net/trananh/v7gdr4n0/

```js
var process;
            var delay = 50;
            var scrollPixel = 20;
            //Fix Undefine pageofset when using IE 8 below;
            function getPapeYOfSet() {
                var yOfSet = (typeof (window.pageYOffset) === "number") ? window.pageYOffset : document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                return yOfSet;
            }

            function goToBottom() {
                process = setInterval(function () {
                    var yOfSet = getPapeYOfSet();
                    if (yOfSet >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
                        clearInterval(process);
                    } else {
                        window.scrollBy(0, scrollPixel);
                    }
                }, delay);
            }
```

JAvascript function goToBottom

Comment: I recommend you try to rephrase the question, it is hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Thank, i have been fixed ^^